# Powershell New-EventLog Error

Tags: powershell

I am getting the error while executing the below command.

Command:

```
New-EventLog –LogName "Windows PowerShell" –Source "Powershell PO Instance"
```

Error:

```
The term 'New-EventLog' is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable program, or script file. Verify the term and try again.
At line:1 char:13
+ New-EventLog  <<<< -LogName "Windows PowerShell" -Source "Powershell PO Instance"
```

Can someone please help me to troubleshoot this?

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a version of PowerShell that has New-EventLog cmdlet. 
Run the following to get a list of commands that are available to you.

```
get-command
```

Comment: I confirmed that this command is not in Powershell 7.1.  What would be a workaround?

Comment: @chribonn you should probably ask that as a separate question, not as an add-on to answer that is 8 yrs old :) 7.x is a different beast altogether. B/c it is supposed to work on all platforms and EventLog is Windows specific, it got removed. The fact that you are trying to create an event log tells me you are on Windows, so you should have access to "Windows" PowerShell (5.1 is the latest). Using that would be a workaround.

Comment: @Adil_Hindistan: I would, but I am on a posting block at the moment. I think I resolved the matter and hopefully will share it by the time the blockage period runs out.